# SUPEE 7405- ISSUES Found for 1.7.0.2 Version (Solutions Inside)

Tags: php, magento

Magento version: 1.7.0.2
PHP version: 5.3.5 (less than 5.4 have issues)

Issues after installing patch: and **SOLUTION!**

**1.** ORDER page is BLANK

**Solution to blank Order page**
*app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
Search for "$links = [];" change to "$links = array();"*

**2.** Broke images in backend. All product images before the patch are Visible on Front and Back end. But, after Patch install, if you upload a product image you will see it is BROKEN/INVISIBLE on Backend, but VISIBLE on Frontend.

**Solution to Broken images**
*Go to /lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES

Find this line:
chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

Modify to this:
chmod($destinationFile, 0755);
In other words, only permissions issue*

**3.** SOAP API URL /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1 (Known issues, reported by someone else.

No solutions yet for SOAP API URL issue... ANYONE GOT IDEAS?

Comment: This is not a question or an answer - you should edit this to be a question, then post the answer yourself

Comment: It's also a shame, because this is probably quite a useful resource for people given the nature of the patch, and would be great it it were structured correctly.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing with the #3 but I think because of third party extension. I have not found the reason yet but below is temporary solution for how to fix it.

Go to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php and comment lines from 960 to 963.

Before:

```
foreach ($fileName as $configFile) {
                $configFile = $this->getModuleDir('etc', $modName).DS.$configFile;
                if ($mergeModel->loadFile($configFile)) {

                    $this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, $mergeModel);
                    $this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND, $mergeModel);
                    $this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMIN, $mergeModel);
                    $this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, $mergeModel);

                    $mergeToObject->extend($mergeModel, true);
                }
            }
```

After:

```
foreach ($fileName as $configFile) {
                $configFile = $this->getModuleDir('etc', $modName).DS.$configFile;
                if ($mergeModel->loadFile($configFile)) {

                    //$this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, $mergeModel);
                    //$this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND, $mergeModel);
                    //$this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMIN, $mergeModel);
                    //$this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, $mergeModel);

                    $mergeToObject->extend($mergeModel, true);
                }
            }
```